# Oracle: replacing tnsnames.ora with LDAP lookup?

Tags: ldap, oracle

How do I go about replacing client-side tnsnames.ora with an ldap query?

I'm not interested in running Oracle LDAP, we have an existing LDAP infrastructure.

I need:

- format of LDAP entry
- how client is configured to fetch the LDAP connection information.  Is this automatic in the OCI runtime?

Oracle 10.2 or 11.x if versions matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oracle can "officially" only use OID or AD as LDAP servers. In LDAP.ORA (in $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin or $TNS_ADMIN) put:

```
DEFAULT_ADMIN_CONTEXT = “ou=ora,dc=company,dc=com”
DIRECTORY_SERVERS = (ldap1.company.com:389, ldap2.company.com:389)
DIRECTORY_SERVER_TYPE = OID
```

The type can be OID or AD. The multiple servers are for redundancy; it will not try each one in turn. Then in SQLNET.ORA:

```
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH=(LDAP, TNSNAMES)
```

The means try LDAP first, then try TNSNAMES.ORA, then give up.

If you want to use a third-party LDAP server, Oracle has a product called [Virtual Directory](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/virtual-directory-ds-132980.pdf) that will act as a proxy between them.

Comment: Yes, this does sounds interesting and very much make sense to avoid manually editting the TNSNAMES.ora, so does OID (Oracle Internet Directory) is free to implement if we have Oracle DB license in production ?

Comment: I believe it is a separate product, check with your Oracle account manager

Comment: ah.. no wonder, if it is separate then it must be purchased with high price (as this is Oracle product).

Answer (score 2):

You do not mention, which LDAP platform you use. I use OpenLDAP for that purpose.

Basically, you need to import some pieces of oid schema.
Then you need to have your tns aliases under `cn=OracleContext,dc=company,dc=com` node.

I created a web application http://www.tnsadmin.com for easy management of tnsnames in LDAP entries, which may be used with any LDAP server. You can also find OpenLDAP schema there.

Comment: Hi Martin, please pay attention to the [guidelines on self promotion](http://serverfault.com/help/behavior) and add a disclaimer about your relationship to this product.